# How can I extract the data from the column of a Dataframe Spark?

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Currently I am adding a new column with the result of a function that contains a request to an external api. To be able to make that request I need the columns "x0" and "x1" of each row, but i really need the value that contains these columns. **How can I get the value of the column inside the function?** or, **how can I pass the column value in the function call?**

```
df.withColumn("result", getDataFromApiRequest(col("x0"), col("x1")))

def getDataFromApiRequest(x0: Column, x1: Column): Column = {
  val x0Value = ???
  val x1Value = ???
   ...
}
```

I've tried to solve this with a UDF function, but it would have to return a Map[String, Any] or a costom type, neither of which is possible in spark 2.x. That is why I am trying to solve it with a scala function.

Comment: See here: https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-extract-dataframe-column-as-list/

There are some examples here you can use as guidance

Comment: @JuanCruzCarrau that solution doesn't work for me.  In that guide it gets the value of a column of a dataframe, but I don't have the dataframe, my variable is of type Column.  Also, following that guide would not solve my problem in a distributed way.